# Infinite Expected Value of Jointly Distributed Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am given a joint pdf function $f(x,y)$ of random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that

$f(x,y) = cxy^{-2}$ when $0 < x < 1$, $1 < y$

$f(x,y) = 0$ otherwise

where $c$ is a constant.

I have calculated the value of $c$, and computed the marginal pdf's of $X$ and $Y $ -- which, from my computations, appear to be independent -- but am having trouble understanding how to calculate the expected value for $Y$.

By integrating $f(x,y)$ over the domain $(0,1)$ with respect to $x$, I computed

$f_{Y}(y) = y^{-2}$

Now, the problem asks to compute $E[Y]$, which led me to try to compute

$\int\limits_1^\infty y(y^{-2})dy$, giving me the result $E[Y] = \lim_{y \to \infty} \ln(y)$.

Intuitively, this doesn't make sense to me. Am I doing something wrong? If not, what does it mean for the expected value of a random variable to be infinite?

Comment: Well, not every random variable has an expectation (see the Cauchy distribution, of which your $Y$ appears to be a specific case, for instance). Were you led to believe (by the exercise or teacher) that $Y$ should have one?

Comment: The exercise asks to find the variance of Y in the next part, which led me to believe $E[Y]$ was finite

Comment: The variance will be "even more infinite".

Comment: Okay, I think I understand the problem now. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quite correct: the integral diverges, and $E[Y]$ does not exist: we can say $E[Y] = +\infty$ in this case, because it diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up! I was asking because the next part of the question is to compute the variance of Y, which I computed to be $\lim_{y \to \infty} y - \lim_{y \to \infty} ln(y) - 1$. Assuming my computations are correct, does this mean that $Var[Y] = \infty$ as well?

Comment: If $Y\notin L^1$, then $Y\notin L^2$ and it has no variance...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what $L^{1}$ and $L^{2}$ are. Can you please explain?

Comment: If it has a finite variance, it must have a finite expectation.
$Y\in L^1$ means $\mathbb E |Y| < \infty$ (absolute value is integrable), and $Y\in L^2$ means $\mathbb E Y^2 < \infty$ (square integrable). When dealing with random variables, you have (one can prove it with Cauchy-Schwartz inequality) $L^2\subset L^1$.

Comment: Oh, okay. I understand your earlier comment now. Thank you! :)